# I'm using mongojs with nodejs on heroku. I am getting an error such as "failed to connect to [127.0.0.1:27017]"

Tags: node.js, heroku, mongojs

I'm using mongojs with nodejs on heroku. After deploying the app and using POST from Curl, i am getting an error such as "failed to connect to [127.0.0.1:27017]". Would be great if someone can help me out...

```
var restify = require("restify");
var databaseUrl = "apipune";
var sensors = ["temp", "light", "humid", "accel", "pir"];
var db = require("mongojs").connect(databaseUrl, sensors);
var server = restify.createServer({name: 'pune.io'});

server
    .use(restify.fullResponse())
    .use(restify.bodyParser());
server.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, function() {
console.log('%s listening at %s', server.name, server.url);
});

server.post('/sensors/temp', function (req, res, next) {
    db.temp.save({value : req.params.value, unit : "C", devid : req.params.did}, function(err, saved) {
          if( err || !saved ) console.log("Value Not Stored");
          else console.log("Value Stored");
        res.send(201);
          });
 });
```